# Image with public URL from GCS won't display immediately after state update but works after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a form that uploads data into mongoDB and an image into a bucket in Google Cloud Storage using [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage). These images have public URLs. After submission, I immediately make an API call into my backend and then update my states. However, the image that was recently uploaded won't display and only responds with a 403 error. [error on get request on the public URL using img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEh7o.png)

**My Submit handler function:**

```
 const handleSubmit = async () => {
 const repairData = new FormData();

 try {
   if (state.device && state.issue && state.image) {
     repairData.append("device", state.device);
     repairData.append("customer", user._id);
     repairData.append("issue", state.issue);
     repairData.append("image", state.image);
     repairData.append("expedite", state.expedite);
     await api.post("/requests/create", repairData, {
       headers: { "auth-token": token },
     });
     setState({
       device: "",
       issue: "",
       image: null,
       expedite: "No",
       hasError: false,
       errorMessage: "",
     });
     setShow(false);
     getRepairs();
   } else {
     setState({
       ...state,
       success: false,
       hasError: true,
       errorMessage: "Missing required information!",
     });
   }
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
};
```

**My API Call Function:**

```
const getRepairs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/user/requests/", {
        headers: { "auth-token": token },
      });
      setRequests([...response.data.repairs]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Only the cached images were displayed. When the page is refreshed, the image will then be displayed accordingly. I can also view the images on browser. I have tried may things such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175740/google-cloud-storage-hosted-images-dont-show-in-my-app) but it still does not work.

Comment: you can add a  `sleep` in your backend to allow some `ms` to the gcp storage, this extra ms can allow to end the processing of the object. Maybe the get operation fires very close to creation, you can also add the code you are using to load the image and how you are using the public url for more context in your question

Comment: Is the bucket public? How do you get the image in your browser?

Comment: @JanHernandez OOOHHHHH silly me. I thought objects are immediately created after submission so I completely focused on my frontend rather than my backend. That's why. However, this is my first time posting here and I can upvote your comment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Jan Hernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11529321/jan-hernandez) said, I checked my google cloud upload function and it was responding even though it's not finished uploading yet! Silly me.

**Original**

```
await storage
    .bucket(process.env.BUCKET_NAME)
    .upload(filename, options, (err, file, cb) => {
      if (err)
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: "Error uploading!",
        });
    });

  return res.status(200).json({
    repair: req.repair,
    message: "Upload successful",
  });
```

**Correct**

```
 await storage
    .bucket(process.env.BUCKET_NAME)
    .upload(filename, options, (err, file, cb) => {
      if (err)
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: "Error uploading!",
        });
      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```